# Getting Whois data for .com domain name whois.verisign-grs.com

Tags: java, whois

I am trying to fetch the whois data for domain names all other  domains(other than .com and .net ) are giving some results for domain names information but while querying to the whois server of .com and .net registry ie.(whois.verisign-grs.com) its giving

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
Whois Server Version 2.0

Domain names in the .com and .net domains can now be registered
with many different competing registrars. Go to http://www.internic.net
for detailed information.

MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.IM.ELITE.WANNABE.TOO.WWW.PLUS613.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZ.MORE.DETAILS.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZ.GET.LAID.AT.WWW.SWINGINGCOMMUNITY.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZOMBIED.AND.HACKED.BY.WWW.WEB-HACK.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZ.IS.0WNED.AND.HAX0RED.BY.SUB7.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.WILL.BE.SLAPPED.IN.THE.FACE.BY.MY.BLUE.VEINED.SPANNER.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.WILL.BE.BEATEN.WITH.MY.SPANNER.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.WAREZ.AT.TOPLIST.GULLI.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.TOTALLY.SUCKS.S3U.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.SOFTWARE.IS.NOT.USED.AT.REG.RU
MICROSOFT.COM.SHOULD.GIVE.UP.BECAUSE.LINUXISGOD.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.RAWKZ.MUH.WERLD.MENTALFLOSS.CA
MICROSOFT.COM.OHMYGODITBURNS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.MORE.INFO.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.MATCHES.THIS.STRING.AT.KEYSIGNERS.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.MAKES.RICKARD.DRINK.SAMBUCA.0800CARRENTAL.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.LOVES.ME.KOSMAL.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.LIVES.AT.SHAUNEWING.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.KNOWS.THAT.THE.BEST.WEB.HOSTING.IS.NASHHOST.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.NOT.YEPPA.ORG
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.IN.BED.WITH.CURTYV.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.IS.HOSTED.ON.PROFITHOSTING.NET
ICROSOFT.COM.HAS.A.PRESENT.COMING.FROM.HUGHESMISSILES.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.FILLS.ME.WITH.BELLIGERENCE.NET
MICROSOFT.COM.CAN.GO.FUCK.ITSELF.AT.SECZY.COM
MICROSOFT.COM.ARE.GODDAMN.PIGFUCKERS.NET.NS-NOT-IN-SERVICE.COM
MICROSOFT.COM

To single out one record, look it up with "xxx", where xxx is one of the
of the records displayed above. If the records are the same, look them up
with "=xxx" to receive a full display for each record.

>>> Last update of whois database: Mon, 19 Dec 2011 10:42:21 UTC <<<

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the 
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is 
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration 
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring 
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to 
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois 
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and 
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or 
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry 
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for 
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information 
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not 
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide 
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only 
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data 
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass 
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone, 
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes 
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation, 
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly 
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to 
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or 
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register 
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right 
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure 
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the 
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign 
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time. 

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

It might be because verisign maintain the "thin" whois server..
can you suggest me the solution to overcome this problem..How can i get the actual registrar to be queried for whois data for .com domain names..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the socket connection to Verisign, instead of querying for `example.com` (where `example.com` is your domain), query for `=example.com`.

You'll get the full information for all the available records.

```
  Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.SHOULD.GIVE.UP.BECAUSE.LINUXISGOD.COM
  IP Address: 209.187.114.147
  Registrar: TUCOWS.COM CO.
  Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
  Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

  Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZOMBIED.AND.HACKED.BY.WWW.WEB-HACK.COM
  IP Address: 216.127.80.46
  Registrar: TUCOWS.COM CO.
  Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
  Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

  Domain Name: MICROSOFT.COM
  Registrar: MARKMONITOR INC.
  Whois Server: whois.markmonitor.com
  Referral URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
  Name Server: NS1.MSFT.NET
  Name Server: NS2.MSFT.NET
  Name Server: NS3.MSFT.NET
  Name Server: NS4.MSFT.NET
  Name Server: NS5.MSFT.NET
  Status: clientDeleteProhibited
  Status: clientTransferProhibited
  Status: clientUpdateProhibited
  Status: serverDeleteProhibited
  Status: serverTransferProhibited
  Status: serverUpdateProhibited
  Updated Date: 09-aug-2011
  Creation Date: 02-may-1991
  Expiration Date: 03-may-2021
```

Then, extract the `Referral URL` from the one corresponding to `Domain Name:` and query the referral.

In case parsing WHOIS is not your main business, you might also want to consider using a third party service for that job.

I'm the author of [RoboWhois WHOIS API](http://www.robowhois.com/). Feel free to give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks It Works... But Can you tell me how is this possible to Query example.com as =example.com and fetch the referal url is it some sort of syntax to query thin whois server or what?????

Comment: Once you have the referral server, in this case `whois.markmonitor.com`, simply open a socket call on port 43 and ask for the same domain.